# ArcGIS server REST API queries fail inconsistently

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, sql-server, arcgis-rest-api

I have a set of map and ESRI feature services running on a 10.1 ArcGIS server with SQL Server back end. When I query the layers for either the geometry or oids using the REST interface, the query only works in certain instances.

1. If I query a point layer the result works as expected and I get the data
2. If I query a polygon layer like this, it fails: http://gistmapsdev.itos.uga.edu/arcgis/rest/services/COD_External/SYR_AR_DynamicLabeling/FeatureServer/5/query?returnGeometry=true&f=json
   I get the error message:

   ```
   {"error":{"code":400,"message":"Unable to complete operation.","details":["Unable to perform query operation."]}}
   ```

The server log files show:

```
    Database error: Operation without query criteria is not allowed.
```

3. However this query (same service, different polygon layer) works as expected and returns the feature geometry:
   http://gistmapsdev.itos.uga.edu/arcgis/rest/services/COD_External/SYR_AR_DynamicLabeling/FeatureServer/6/query?returnGeometry=true&f=json

There are 2 polygon layers that I can query and get the expected result but all other polygon layers fail and for the life of me I cannot see any difference in the properties of the feature classes that fail vs those that do not.

4. If I dirty the query (by adding a where clause 1=1) I get the expected result; so for example, the query in point 2 above works when I add where=1%3D1

What I’ve looked at:

a.  I have not hit the max feature limit set on the server or the service

b.  the behavior is consistent across browsers

c.  the behavior is consistent using either get or post

d.  I have rebuilt the spatial indices and cleared the caches

e.  The behavior is consistent if I ask for json or html response

This is different than the NIM086349 bug described on this site at 52612/arcgis-server-10-1-inconsistent-querying-errors - which fails on alternate queries. In my case the failure is consistent and appears to be tied to particular data types and data layers.

Can you provide any pointers or areas that I should look at?